# Android: Add a listfragment to the transaction

Tags: java, android, android-listfragment

I try to add the listfragment with fragmentTransation.add(...) but I can't do it, it is an error. I want to add a listfragment like a normal fragment, is it possible?

Here is my activity main code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FragmentList fragmentList = FragmentList.createFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.relativeLayout,fragmentList); //WRONG
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Here is my listfragment class code:

```
public class FragmentList extends ListFragment
{
public static FragmentList createFragment()
{
    FragmentList fragmentList = new FragmentList();
    return fragmentList;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    ListView listView = getListView();
    String[] stringa = {"A","B","C"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stringa);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
}
```

Comment: post the error please!!

Comment: @ApolloSoftware there is a red line under fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.relativeLayout,fragmentList);

Comment: Can you extend public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity, FragmentActivity?

Comment: Also try getFragmentManager

Comment: @ApolloSoftware No, I cant't extend more than one class in Java

Comment: ublic class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity

Comment: @ApolloSoftware What?? `AppCompatActivity` already extends `FragmentActivity` and that is not the problem

Comment: what i meant to say

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You cannot use `android.app.ListFragment` with `SupportFragmentManger` you can use `getFragmentManager()` for that.

Basically, check your `import` statements.

Or you may extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead and define your own layout with a `<ListView>` (like you already are doing)

Or you can use `android.support.v4.app.ListFragment`

---

More importantly, though

2) `getListView()` can't be called from `onCreate` because there is no view yet.

You only need `onCreateView`

```
public class FragmentList extends ListFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        String[] stringa = {"A","B","C"};

        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stringa);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Plus,

```
getFragmentManager() // Change accordingly
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.relativeLayout,new FragmentList())
    .commit();
```

Comment: Yes, it will with `ListFragment`

Comment: There's a support [`ListFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.html), btw.

Comment: @cricket_007 I've got this error Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created

Comment: That error would come from an Activity, not any Fragment code I've shown

Comment: @cricket_007 I wrote your code, but it always gives me the same error

Comment: @cricket_007 Ah, furthermore I can't use findViewById, it is underlined with red

Comment: @cricket_007 I solved other errors. I had to move the creation of the list in onViewCreated and I have to change the name of the list

Comment: Sorry about that. `rootView.findViewById` is what I missed